# FFmpeg zoompan animation results in zig-zag pattern

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

The goal is for a user to specify a zoomPoint in a video and we then render that using FFmpeg. There will be a zoom in and zoom out animation. Here are some example values:

```
"scale":4,        # Scale factor, here x4
"offset":0,       # Start zooming in after 0ms
"duration":5000,  # Stay zoomed in for 5000ms
"marginX":80,     # Zoom x to 80% of video width 
"marginY":10      # Zoom y to 10% of video height
```

Based on that input, I am running the following, simplified FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i "/tmp/input.mp4" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -vf "scale=iw*2:ih*2,zoompan=fps=30:z='if(gte(it,0.0)*lt(it,5.0), min(pzoom+0.2, 4),if(gte(it,5.0)*lt(it,5.5), max(pzoom-0.2, 1), 1))':d=1:s=1512x982:x='(iw - iw/4)*(80/100)':y='(ih - ih/4)*(10/100)'" /tmp/output.mp4
```

The animation duration is `0.5s`, the video framerate is `30fps`, and so there are `0.5 / (1/30) = 15` animation frames.

Zoom distance is `scale - 1 = 3` in this case, which makes the zoom increment `3 / 15 = 0.2`.

This results in the following **example video**: [click here](https://players.akamai.com/players/hlsjs?streamUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdev-static-video-resources.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Fhls%2Fscenes%2Ff20a0834-8bd3-457d-86e4-15204fc0572c%2Ftrimmed%2Fstream-trimmed.m3u8)

While the zoom animation ends in the correct position, you will notice it arrives at that position in a **zig-zag pattern**, where it starts by zooming into the top-right corner, before changing direction towards the correct position.

I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to animate the zoom in a straight line to the specified x/y position.

Any tips are welcome, thanks!

Comment: zoom var? `...(iw - iw/zoom/4)*(80/100...`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов thanks for the suggestion! However, this results in the video zooming to one extreme corner, and no longer makes it zoom to the correct end position.

Comment: maybe, that: `:x='iw*0.8 - iw*0.8/zoom'
:y='ih*0.1 - ih*0.1/zoom'`

Answer (score 1):

The zoompans x and y percentage values are applied to the inputs width/height after deducting the zoomed areas width/height.

At x = 100%, an input with a 1000 pixel width, at a 4X zoom would place the x axis of the zoomed area at 750, not 1000 pixels.

```
 iw-(iw/zoom)

 1000-(1000/4) = 750
```

This is not critical, other than the fact we cannot assume percentage input values represent a true percentage of the inputs **full** input width/height.

If we need to zoom to a specific x axis pixel location, the following equation will determine the required percentage value.

```
 (x*100)/(iw-(iw/zoom)) = %
```

As an example, using the above equation we can calculate the percentage for x = 275 pixels for a 4X zoom ratio.

```
 (275x100)/(1000-(1000/4)) = 36.66%
```

#### Script

Zoompan filter calculations are frame based. To enable the input of time based values (seconds and milliseconds only), and because of the need for identical values to be input multiple times, the following script uses set variables for clarity.

The frame rate of 30fps, appears three times in the main script.  If regularly working with different frame rates, an additional set variable would be advisable.

- `set R=` Zoom ratio
- `set Z=` Zoom start time
- `set D=` Zoom duration
- `set X=` X percent co-ordinate (horizontal)
- `set Y=` Y percent co-ordinate (vertical)

```
 set R=4
 set Z=0
 set D=0.5
 set X=80
 set Y=20

 ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=10*iw:-2,zoompan=z='if(gte(in,(%Z%*30)+1),min(pzoom+(%R%-1)/(%D%*30),%R%))':d=1:fps=30\:x='iw*(%X%/100)-(iw/zoom*(%X%/100))':y='ih*(%Y%/100)-(ih/zoom*(%Y%/100))'" -s 1512x982 out.mkv
```

To apply a zoom and pan to the centre, or one of the four corners, or edges of the frame, the following x and y values are required.

- `x=0 y=0`         Top Left
- `x=100 y=0`       Top Right
- `x=0 y=100`       Bottom Left
- `x=100 y=100`     Bottom Right
- `x=50 y=0`        Top
- `x=0 y=50`        Left
- `x=50 y=100`      Bottom
- `x=100 y=50`      Right
- `x=50 y=50`       Centre